# Upload a file of over 2GB to GitHub repository

Tags: github, git-lfs

I am trying to upload a json file of 2.3GB to GitHub repository but it raises an error as the maximum size for GitHub with Git LFS seems to be 2GB. What can I do to upload it? I am deploying an app and I need all the files together in the same repo.

Comment: I don't think that's the purpose of Github. You can try to break the Json into smaller files.

Comment: Consider asking a question about alternative ways of deploying something so large.

Answer (score 0):

Git LFS handles files of nearly arbitrary size just fine (although hashing them can be expensive).  However, GitHub has a 2 GiB file limitation for individual and free accounts; the limit is 4 GiB for team and 5 GiB for enterprise accounts.

If you have an individual or free account, you'll need to store this data elsewhere.  You may find that storing it in a cloud syncing service or on an external LFS server (with `lfs.url` in `.lfsconfig`) may work, and if it's not in LFS, you can download it as part of your deployment step.